# Find $f(x)$ provided with three remainders and quotients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $3$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $x+1$, the remainder is $-19$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $x-2$,the remainder is $32$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $3x^2-x+18$, the remainder is $-3x+66$. Find $f(x)$.

I am trying to set four unknowns and use the division algorithm, but it is very confusing as it involves lots of substituting. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem).

Comment: I understand the remainder theorem and division algorithm but I don't understand how to apply it in this question

Comment: You did not state the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x - 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your polynomial is
$f(x) = (3x^2 - x + 18)(ax + b) -3x + 66$

Now put $x = -1$ and $x = 2$ in this.